# "parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token c

Tags: java, rest

I want to post json data my Java Rest Service , 
when Post data from jQyery Ajax to Rest Service that return:

"parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token c

Java Object Class

```
public class SimpleObject {
private int id;
private String name;

public SimpleObject(){

}

public SimpleObject(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Rest Service

```
      @POST
      @Path("/postjson")
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      public Response jsonFunc(SimpleObject simpleobjcet){
          String output = simpleobjcet.toString();
          return Response.status(201).entity(output).build();
      }
```

jQuery Ajax client code

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/RestExample/resources/MyRestService/postjson',
        type: 'POST',
        data: '{"id":0,"name":"salih"}',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {    
            console.log(responseData);
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown);
            alert('Error' + textStatus);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Who is giving this error? The Java compiler? jQuery?

Comment: Take a look at the network communication. Open the developer toos of your browser, and see what did the server reply to your response. I am suspicious about `String output = simpleobjcet.toString()`.

Comment: Giving jQuery , When I monitor   browser network with f12 developer tool , Http response 200 ok , but jQuery giving this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Tichodroma , I found solutions , I changed RestService code and it Works!
New RestService code ..

```
 @POST
      @Path("/postjson")
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      public SimpleObject json(SimpleObject simpleObject){
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String jsonInString="";
            try {
                jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(simpleObject);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(jsonInString);       
          return simpleObject;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleObject.toString()` does not return JSON. Since you set `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery expects the response to be JSON, too.

Either change `SimpleObject.toString()` to produce JSON, or change `dataType` to `text`.